# Socket server communicate with 2 clients at 1 thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

A client communicate with authserver to recieve a nickname, and the auhserver send the nickname to clients and another server, in order to client communicate with the other server.
My problem is how to make the other server connect with the client and authserver without making new communication thread for each one?

```
    public class Aatombolaserver extends Thread {
 /***in order to differentiate between client socket**/
protected Socket clientSocket;
         String serverHostname = new String ("127.0.0.1");
         Socket authSocket = null;
/**** constructor**/
private Aatombolaserver (Socket clientSoc)
 {clientSocket = clientSoc;
  authSocket = clientSoc;
//store the socket of the coming client
 start();//execute the run method
 }
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
     /**** Create a server socket and wait for a connection**/
     ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
//          ServerSocket serverSocket1 = null;
    try {
         serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9091);
//         serverSocket1 = new ServerSocket(9092);
         System.out.println ("Connection Socket Created");
         try { System.out.println ("Waiting for a client to connect");
             while (true){//wait for clients
                //accept the client request and proceed with the thread creation
               new Aatombolaserver(serverSocket.accept());
             }
         }
         catch (IOException e){
         System.err.println("Accept failed.");
         System.exit(1);
         }
    } catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 10008.");
         System.exit(1);
    }//end try
    /************Close Socket*******************/
 finally {
     try {  serverSocket.close(); }
    catch (IOException e){
         System.err.println("Could not close port: 10008.");
         System.exit(1);
        }
    }//end finally
 }
```

Comment: Typically for a server you need 1 thread that waits for new connections to the ServerSocket (`accept` is blocking) and 1 thread per connected client so the server can `read` (which is blocking) their data. If you don't care about reading, you don't need a thread.

Comment: Consider NIO, or use a framework around NIO such as Netty

Comment: this my code how i can edit?